# How To Pre-Select CheckBox in SwiftUI

Tags: checkbox, swiftui

This is my CheckBoxField

How do I display a checkboxfield with a checkmark shows it was pre-checked already?

Here is how I use it. I would like to see the checkboxfield has a checkmark in there when loading like this one.

[image]

```
CheckboxField(
    id: "Completed",
    label: "Completed",
    callback: self.checkboxSelected
)

func checkboxSelected(id: String, isMarked: Bool) {
    print("This is done ->>> \(id) is marked: \(isMarked)")
}

import SwiftUI

struct CheckboxField: View {
    let id: String
    let label: String
    let size: CGFloat
    let color: Color
    let textSize: Int
    let callback: (String, Bool)->()
    
    init(
    id: String,
    label:String,
    size: CGFloat = 10,
    color: Color = Color.black.opacity(0.68),
    textSize: Int = 14,
    callback: @escaping (String, Bool)->()
    ) {
        self.id = id
        self.label = label
        self.size = size
        self.color = color
        self.textSize = textSize
        self.callback = callback
    }
    
    @State var isMarked:Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action:{
            self.isMarked.toggle()
            self.callback(self.id, self.isMarked)
        }) {
            HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 10) {
                Image(systemName: self.isMarked ? "checkmark.square" : "square")
                .renderingMode(.original)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                Text(label)
                .font(Font.system(size: size))
                .foregroundColor(Color.black.opacity(0.87))
                Spacer()
            }.foregroundColor(self.color)
        }
        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make

```
@State var isMarked:Bool = false
```

Into a `Binding` instead.

```
@Binding var isMarked: Bool
```

This way, you can access `isMarked` from both the superview and the checkmark  view itself. You can also avoid using a closure.

Example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var firstMarked = false
    @State var secondMarked = true /// at load, the second one will be checked already
    @State var thirdMarked = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            CheckboxField(id: "Completed", label: "Completed", isMarked: $firstMarked)
            CheckboxField(id: "Completed", label: "Completed", isMarked: $secondMarked)
            CheckboxField(id: "Completed", label: "Completed", isMarked: $thirdMarked)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct CheckboxField: View {
    let id: String
    let label: String
    let size: CGFloat
    let color: Color
    let textSize: Int

    @Binding var isMarked: Bool /// Binding here!
    
    init(
    id: String,
    label:String,
    size: CGFloat = 10,
    color: Color = Color.black.opacity(0.68),
    textSize: Int = 14,
    isMarked: Binding<Bool>
    ) {
        self.id = id
        self.label = label
        self.size = size
        self.color = color
        self.textSize = textSize
        self._isMarked = isMarked /// to init, you need to add a _
    }
    
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action:{
            self.isMarked.toggle() /// just toggle without closure
        }) {
            HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 10) {
                Image(systemName: self.isMarked ? "checkmark.square" : "square")
                .renderingMode(.original)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                Text(label)
                .font(Font.system(size: size))
                .foregroundColor(Color.black.opacity(0.87))
                Spacer()
            }.foregroundColor(self.color)
        }
        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Second checkbox starts out checked already]

Comment: How do I add that to here?  I have multiple checkboxs in the same view.               CheckboxField(
    id: "Completed",
    label: "Completed",
    callback: self.checkboxSelected
)

Comment: @Michelle I added an example.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `isMarked` State from `false` to `true`. Because `@State` should only be used in the current view, it's a best practice to make the `isMarked` variable `private`.

```swift
@State private var isMarked: Bool = true
```

This makes your Button checked when the view is getting loaded.

You can then access your button's state using `@Binding` in other views. The Binding and State variables have to have the same name otherwise, the Binding doesn`t know what to reference.